# Do I have to create a directive to resolve this problem

Tags: angular, storybook

This is the story for Badge Directive.

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';
import { BadComponent } from '../projects/ui-elements/src/lib/bad/bad.component';

const Template: Story<BadComponent> = () => ({
   
    template: '<div   badge ></div>'
});

export default {
    title: 'Elements/Badge',
    component:BadComponent
};

export const Principal = Template.bind({});
Principal.args = {
    template: '<div badge>small </div>'

};
```

```js
export type BadgeSizes = "small" | "medium" | "large";

export type BadgePositions =
  | "top-right"
  | "top-left"
  | "bottom-right"
  | "bottom-left";

export type BadgeVariants = "primary" | "secondary";
```

This is  mon BadgeDirective.ts . There is all function for the badge

```js
import {  Directive,  ElementRef,  Inject,  Input,  OnChanges,  OnDestroy,  SimpleChanges} from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";
import { BadgeSizes, BadgePositions, BadgeVariants } from "./badge.interface";

@Directive({
  selector: "[badge]"
})
export class BadgeDirective implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() badge = null;
  @Input() size: BadgeSizes = "medium";
  @Input() position: BadgePositions = "top-right";
  @Input() customBadgeClasses: string | null = null;
  @Input() variant: BadgeVariants = "secondary";

  badgeElement: HTMLElement | null = null;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) {}
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ("badge" in changes) {
      const value = `${changes.badge.currentValue}`.trim();
      if (value?.length > 0) {
        this.updateBadgeText(value);
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.badgeElement) {
      this.badgeElement.remove();
    }
  }

  private updateBadgeText(value: string) {
    if (!this.badgeElement) {
      this.createBadge(value);
    } else {
      this.badgeElement.textContent = value;
    }
  }

  private createBadge(value: string): HTMLElement {
    const badgeElement = this.document.createElement("span");
    this.addClasses(badgeElement);
    badgeElement.textContent = value;
    this.elRef.nativeElement.classList.add("badge-container");
    this.elRef.nativeElement.appendChild(badgeElement);
    return badgeElement;
  }

  private addClasses(badgeElement: HTMLElement) {
    const [vPos, hPos] = this.position.split("-");
    badgeElement.classList.add("badge", vPos, hPos);
    if (this.customBadgeClasses) {
      const customClasses = this.customBadgeClasses.split(" ");
      badgeElement.classList.add(...customClasses);
    }
    badgeElement.classList.add(this.variant);
    badgeElement.classList.add(this.size);
  }
}
```

Hello i have a problem with storybook. I want to create a badge(i don't know if i have to do a comonent or a directive but i created a directive).
the badge is half displayed. the number just above is not displayed. please help

Answer (score 0):

(i don't know if i have to do a comonent or a directive but i created a directive).

We can not just choose to write a Directive or a Component!

**Directive**: Used to add some behavior to the DOM e.g. change the text color or add some text.

**Component**: Is a directive with a view (a class with a view if you will).
And it's the most basic UI building blocks of angular app.
So, whenever you want to create a template and display some data you should use components.

Your question is not clear enough, but it seems that you should use a component.

Comment: thanks. My question is how to do a badge component in storybook